# set the default keyboard type to ascii mode

Tags: centos, terminal, keyboard, ascii

I am running CentOS 6.5 and I am having problems setting the default keyboard mode to ascii for the virtual terminals. Currently, only the system console defaults to ascii mode, but if I log in to an other virtual terminal, it defaults to unicode mode. These are my configurations:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/keyboard
KEYTABLE="us"
MODEL="pc105"
LAYOUT="us"
KEYBOARDTYPE="pc"

# /etc/sysconfig/i18n
LANG="en_US.ISO88591"
SYSFONT="iso01.16"

# /etc/sysconfig/console
KEYMAP="us"
FONT="iso01.16"
UNICODE=""
```

Besides, since these files are more or less documented, I am not sure what is the difference between them and what variables can we assign into them. Any advice?

Comment: I know a workaroud for this but it's not really satisfactory. I could add a line like :
`
# /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
setsysfont
`

to my login script so that on login, /etc/sysconfig/i18n would get sourced. But this would just shift from utf-8 to ascii. What I'd like is to have my virtual terminals start off in ascii mode.

Comment: You may be mixing up terms here. ASCII only covers character codes 0-127, and overlaps exactly with UTF-8 (meaning 0-127 mean the same thing in both ASCII and UTF-8). From your question it looks like you are using ISO-8859-1, which is an extension to ASCII that is not compatible with UTF-8 (all of them share 0-127 but what 128 and beyond mean is different in ISO-8859-1 vs UTF-8).

Comment: The terminal and console both have two modes: ascii and utf-8 (as determined by the kbd_mode command). Since i'm using latin1 on my vt it doesn't makes sense to run in utf-8 mode. So I want to run in ascii mode. Ascii here means any byte-wide charset like the iso8859 kinds.

Comment: The difference between ascii and unicode modes is that in ascii mode, the kernel receives each characters of the keyboard as a plain byte. In unicode mode, the kernel might expect up to three bytes for some char. I'm not sure about this but I also think that the keyboard driver reads each char as an utf-16 double-char and sends them endoded in utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` is the place to make changes.  But it contains the proper settings in your example.  No change should be made to `/etc/sysconfig/keyboard` (if it worked, leave it alone).  Actually on my Centos6.x, I have a **directory** at `/etc/sysconfig/console` (which could contain a keymaps) — and a [mailing list discussion from 2002](https://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-list/2002-March/msg01636.html) hints that it has been a directory at least that long..  Some *other* systems have a file there, e.g., [*Linux From Scratch*](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/7.1/chapter07/console.html).

To get "ASCII" as requested means that you have to change your system locale, which is set in `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` using the `LANG` property.  By default, that would have

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

(or some other `LANG` with "UTF-8", giving more or less the same effect).  I changed my machine to match yours, checking that the values matched the machine:

```
LANG="en_US.iso88591"
SYSFONT="iso01.16"
```

that is, the `LANG` value is in `locale -a`:

```
en_SG.utf8
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
en_ZA
```

and `SYSFONT` is the name of a console font file:

```
/lib/kbd/consolefonts/iso01.16.gz
```

After making the change, I rebooted and see "ASCII" behavior on each of the tty's (2-6, since X is running on `tty1`).  But checking with `showconsolefont` shows that it still loads the original font.  That is set in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`.  Editing *that* file to change the `SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16` to `SYSFONT=iso01.16` gives the desired effect.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot after changing SYSFONT in CentOS6]

That is, the ISO-8859-1 font is loaded.  The keyboard (being US) will only do "ASCII" without some interesting keymap.

Further reading:

- [Appendix D. The sysconfig Directory](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-The_sysconfig_Directory.html) (Red Hat)
- [28.1.13. /etc/sysconfig/i18n](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-sysconfig-i18n.html) (CentOS 5: users of 6 and 7 are directed to Red Hat)